# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat "timezone file"

Tags: linux, time-zone, stat

I was developing a react app and suddenly it stopped, it's never have happened before so i am curious what made it happened?

I don't know if there was a file named "/Kolkata"  before but it is present now with `lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root`

Below is the error i got, react app stopped and throwed up this error:

```
node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Kolkata'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Kolkata'
}
```

I know that the error is about "no file or directory present" but i am more intersted in "Why this error actually occur and possibly why or on what instance this error occurs if it is normal?"

Answer (score 0):

It's not a regular file, it's a symbolic link (as the `l` in the 1st column tells you), and it looks like it's a *broken* symlink – i.e. it's pointing to another path that no longer exists.

Symlinks do not automatically disappear when they're broken; you can still see them in directory listings, and you can call `lstat()` on them – but you will of course get a "Doesn't exist" error when calling plain `stat()` as that's supposed to return the information about the target, not about the link, and there indeed is *no* target.

So it's normal to get this error if your app has been written to list a directory and call stat() on each item it finds, and if it happens to find a broken symlink. You would get the same error if you tried to `cat` or otherwise open the broken link. (The `ls` tool works fine because it uses lstat(), but if you tried `ls -L` you'd still get the same error.)

Who created the link? Somebody with root or `sudo` rights (probably you). Check the sudo log in `journalctl -t sudo` or /var/log/auth.log just in case.

Why did your app decide to look at it? It's looking for a *timezone file*, so it must have gotten this path either from the `TZ` environment variable or from the `/etc/timezone` file. Check the contents of both – if they're present, they should be saying "Asia/Kolkata" instead. (If either of them is absent, that's fine.)

Additionally, check the `/etc/localtime` file – it defines the system-wide timezone, and it should be a symlink to some file under `/usr/share/zoneinfo` (although it might sometimes be just a plain copy of that file, but I'd recommend replacing it with a symlink then).

Of course, it is also possible that there's code *in your program* asking it to load that timezone specifically – and is giving the wrong timezone name to the function.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, the reason i put this question here because it is not related to programming as per i am concerned, it was not doing anything "file related" hence this error should not occur and i just checked `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Region/` is missing i don't know why?

Comment: I've added some more text about timezone data files specifically. Yes, it exists in /usr/share/zoneinfo, but is that where the symlink actually points? The symlink itself shouldn't _be_ in the `/` root directory, so I'm assuming its target is wrong too.